# Programmatically unfocus a TextField?

Tags: focus, javafx-2, textfield

On my view I only have one editable content: Text in a TextField. The problem is that as a user one never gets rid of the focus (because there is nothing else to focus on), once the TextField is focused. I want to remove the focus from the TextField when the user presses Enter. I know how to react to the Enter key being pressed, but I don't know how to unfocus a control/TextField programmatically?

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Try this function: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setFocused(boolean)
with "false" as an argument

Comment: Tahnks, but you linked my question, not the other one where my question is probably answered ;-)

Answer (score 9):

I admit I crossposted, but I got a reply there which I want to share here:

Call `requestFocus()` on the parent, e.g. in my case the HBox containing the TextField.

Full example on https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10852574

Comment: if you wrap textField.getParent.requestFocus() call with  PlatForm.RunLater in initialize() method , then you don't need extra enter key logic :)

Comment: Well, actually I want the focus to be removed after the user edited the TextField and confirmed his change by pressing enter :-)

Comment: Hmm ok , i misinterpreted your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I'm sorry, but I edited and added the correct link, if it for some reason isn't showing here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setFocused(boolean)

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this method is protected and not public, so I can't access it without subclassing a TextField, which seems a little bit overkill. Am I missing something? Shouldn't be so hard to unfocus a JavaFX control ):

Comment: you can cheat a little by requesting focus for a different TextField, perhaps an invisible one ;-)

Comment: Hmm, the next question then would be if one can focus an invisible TextField :P And I still would have to subclass one. Maybe an idea, still sounds unintuitive (not your fault), I'll wait a little bit if anyone maybe knows of a simple / more natural way.

Comment: Hmm actually you were quite close to the fix: Requesting focus for another control, which doesn't have to be a TextField ;-)