# remove default focus from TextField JavaFX

Tags: javafx, textfield, scenebuilder

I have designed some TextField in a form by SceneBuilder, when I run the code, one of the TextFields has been clicked by default, I want when I run the code, none of the TextFields get selected by default and user select a TextFiled.

UPDATE: As you see in [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uyg4vq8kwqq77n9/aaa.png?dl=0) image I want to make the first field like other two field when code runs(no curser in field)

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically unfocus a TextField?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883357/programmatically-unfocus-a-textfield)

Comment: @maxd no! I have already tried that solution but not worked for me

Comment: `setFocus(false)` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha there is no `setFocus` function for TextField

Comment: @Yashar Ahh, my fault, that is a protected method. Check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As there is no public method to achieve this, there is no direct way. Though, you can use a trick to do it. You can have a `BooleanProperty` just to check when the control is focused for the first time. Listen to `focusProperty()` of the control and when it is focused for the first time, delegate the focus to its container. For the rest of the focus, it will work as it should.

**Example:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final BooleanProperty firstTime = new SimpleBooleanProperty(true); // Variable to store the focus on stage load
        VBox vBox = new VBox(10);
        vBox.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        TextField t1 = new TextField();
        TextField t2 = new TextField();
        TextField t3 = new TextField();
        t1.setPromptText("FirstName");
        t2.setPromptText("LastName");
        t3.setPromptText("Email");
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(new HBox(t1, t2), t3);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vBox, 300, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
        t1.focusedProperty().addListener((observable,  oldValue,  newValue) -> {
            if(newValue && firstTime.get()){
                vBox.requestFocus(); // Delegate the focus to container
                firstTime.setValue(false); // Variable value changed for future references
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

On initial screen load :

[image]

Comment: I'm in the same situation and got a question: a simple Boolean could not fit? Why **firstTime** as a *BooleanProperty*?

Comment: While using JavaFX, you should declare all your variables as properties. Moreover, `firstTime` is used inside a lambda which means it needs to be final and its state cannot be changed. If you declare it as **boolean**, you will not be able to re-assign its value.

Answer (score 28):

In my case the accepted answer is not working. But this worked:

i requested focus for parent wrapped in runLater.

```
@FXML
public void initialize() {

    //unfocus pathField
    Platform.runLater( () -> root.requestFocus() );
}
```

Direct call of requestFocuss does not work.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem with a non - editable TextField, which got selected and highlighted every time.

Solved it by setting myTextField.setFocusTraversable(false);

Note that in this case the focus goes to the next UI element an you must set every single element you don't want focused. You lose also the ability to select the element via the Tab key.

The ApiDoc states that setFocusTraversable() is false by default, but that seems not to work, unless explicitly called.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set the focus traversable to false in the initialize method. Here is an example:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    yourTextField.setFocusTraversable(false);
}
```

Comment: nothing new compared to https://stackoverflow.com/a/39248821/203657,  is there ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html)

```
TextField textField = new TextField();
textField.styleProperty().bind(
                Bindings
                        .when(textField.focusedProperty())
                        .then("-fx-prompt-text-fill: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -30%);")
                        .otherwise("-fx-prompt-text-fill: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -30%);"));
```

This will keep your prompt text visible even when the TextField is focused, as long it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

1. Open the relevant FXML file in SceneBuilder window
2. Click on the specific TextField
3. Click on right side "Properties" section
4. Scroll to find "Focus Traversable" and,
5. Turn it off as in the attached screenshot
   [image]