# JavaFX default element

Tags: java, javafx, textfield, scenebuilder

So I'm just starting to learn JavaFX, and I made a couple of TextFields with Scene Builder. I assigned some prompt text to every TextField, but when I start my application, the first TextField is already selected, so I don't see the prompt text. Can I do something about it?

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051225/remove-default-focus-from-textfield-javafx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to make the prompt text stay visible when the `TextField` has focus.

The reason why the prompt text disappears is because `modena.css` (the default stylesheet used in JavaFX 8+) makes the prompt text's fill transparent when the `TextField` has focus. You can change this by using your own CSS to style the prompt text. There are a couple ways you can do this:

- CSS File:

  ```css
  .text-field:focused {
      -fx-prompt-text-fill: inherit;
  }
  ```
- Code:

  ```
  textField.setStyle("-fx-prompt-text-fill: inherit;");
  ```

  Note you can set the `style` from Scene Builder.